# How To Rewrite Unqualified Address In Postfix So That The Local Domain Is Not Used Automatically

Tags: email, ubuntu, postfix-mta

I would like to configure Postfix to rewrite only unqualified recipient email addresses (that is addresses that would go into the To: section of an email), to use the commercial domain name (as in, .com) of our client and not the local intranet domain of our client's environment, which is Postfix's default behavior for rewriting invalid addresses.

Just to be on the same page, invalid addresses here to me are addresses that do not include an '@' sign so are not valid SMTP addresses

Please also note, as an unfortunate, confounding circumstance, the local intranet domain of this clients environment is *actually* a named .local domain which can cause an unknown amount of issues as ".local" is a special-use reserved top-level domain by the IETF so, while I don't think that is actually causing an issue here, it should be stated. And this has caused issues with us before with regards to multicast vs unicast-dns

Details:

**Unqualified Recipient Example:** sam0161

**Qualified Recipient Example:** sam0161@ClientDomain.com

**Local Intranet Domain:** ClientDomain.local

**Public Commerical Domain:** ClientDomain.com

**Postfix Version:** 3.4.13

**Server OS:**  Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS Focal

Expected Behavior:

The command

`date | mail -s "Test Email" sam0161`

Should email to

sam0161@hostname.ClientDomain.com

The command

`date | mail -s "Test Email" sam0161@AnotherValidDomain.com`

Should email to

sam0161@AnotherValidDomain.com (I.E it is left alone)

Actual Results:

`date | mail -s "Test Email" sam0161`

is sent to

sam0161.Hostname.local

`date | mail -s "Test Email" sam0161@AnotherValidDomain.com`

is sent to sam0161@AnotherValidDomain.com

(*Note: This part is correct, we want to leave it as is, I'm including it here just for background and completeness*)

I have tried the following In order to achieve this

in /etc/postfix/main.cf

1. Configured

   mydomain = ClientDomain.com

   append_dot_mydomain = yes

   append_at_myorigin = no

   myorigin = $mydomain

   inet_interfaces = all

The Logic for these configuration options is described by the local_header_rewrite_clients in postfix.org

> Rewrite message header addresses in mail from these clients and update incomplete addresses with the domain name in $myorigin or $mydomain; either don't rewrite message headers from other clients at all, or rewrite message headers and update incomplete addresses with the domain specified in the remote_header_rewrite_domain parameter.

2. Configured

   remote_header_rewrite_domain = "clientDomain.com"

The Logic is to cover all mail traffic to ensure it is rewritten, even though in this environment and setup none of it should technically be considered "Remote" clients.

3. Configured

   recipient_canonical_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical

Logic is to "force" the recipient to be rewritten via Regular Expression. Please note, this is where things are a bit odd for me, as a manual test of the lookup table shows that the recipient should be rewritten, but when mail is sent, the recipient address is still shown to be sam0161.Hostname.local

Example:

`/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical`

`!/.*@.*/ @clientDomain.com`

`postmap -q "sam0161" regexp:/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical`

`@clientDomain.com`

`postmap -q "sam0161@AnotherValidDomain.com" regexp:/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical`

`(returns nothing, desired behavior)`

`date | mail -s "Test" sam0161`

`postfix ignores canonical mapping and sends to hostname.domain.local`

`postfix/local[65681]: A6E459K616: to=<sam0161@.hostname.domain.local>, relay=local, delay=0.09, delays=0.07/0/0/0.01,`

In short, it looks like I cannot circumvent the default behavior of appending the "myhostname" value, as returned by the gethostname() method call used by Postfix, to unqualified recipients. Even if I explicitly redefine the logic to use a *specific* domain different than the local one and or attempt to manually force the use of a different domain through canonical address rewriting .

Could anyone please advise if what I'm trying to do is possible? Or does Postfix simply *not* let you rewrite unqualified addresses to use a specific domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been corrected - It turns out the mail *client* not postfix was appending the .hostname.local to the traffic *before* it hit postfix. Meaning the Regular Expression Logic would never evaluate to "true" as an '@' sign was always present.

The fix, therefore, is to do something like

/.*@hostname.local/ clientDomain.com

It goes without saying this a gross failure in troubleshooting on my part with assumptions being made that the problem started and ended with Postfix.